# TF400898: An Internal Error Occurred. Activity Id: 1fc05eca-fed8-4065-ae1a-fc8f2741c0ea

Tags: python, django, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

i’m trying to push files into git repo via azure API but getting activity_id error. I followed their [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pushes/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#add-a-text-file) and trying to add simple file in my repo.
Here is my code:

```
import requests, base64
pat_token = "xxxx-xxxxx-xxxx"
b64Val = base64.b64encode(pat_token.encode()).decode()
payload = {
 "refUpdates": [
   {
     "name": "refs/heads/main",
     "oldObjectId": "505aae1f15ae153b7fc53e8bdb79ac997caa99e6"
   }
 ],
"commits": [
  {
    "comment": "Added task markdown file.",
    "changes": [
      {
        "changeType": "add",
        "item": {
          "path": "TimeStamps.txt"
         },
        "newContent": {
          "content": "# Tasks\n\n* Item 1\n* Item 2",
          "contentType": "rawtext"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
 ]
}
headers = {
'Authorization': 'Basic %s' % b64Val,
'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}
params = (
    ('api-version', '6.0'),
)
response = requests.post('https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repo}/pushes', headers=headers, data=payload, params=params)
```

Anyone knows how to solve this issue? I have also added this [issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/TF400898:-An-Internal-Error-Occurred-Ac/1616837?space=21) on their developer community

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’ve fixed that error, actually the payload was not in json format so i have to make it as json and after that it worked fine.
Like this

```
response = requests.post('https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repoId}/pushes', headers=headers,  params=params, data=json.dumps(payload))
```